# How to split text from web on newlines in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to read the full text from the Project Gutenberg Les Miserables Tome 1 from the following URL.

http://corpus-db.org/api/id/17489/fulltext

I want to split this text into lines before working with it further.
My code to accomplish this task follows:

```
import urllib.request
def get_les_mis():
    url = "http://corpus-db.org/api/id/17489/fulltext"
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
            text = (f.read().decode('utf-8'))
            lines = text.splitlines()
            for line in lines:
                print(line)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print(e.reason)
```

Unfortunately, when I test this function in the terminal, the output seems to be a single list containing the whole string, including many newline characters. The splitlines function doesn't seem to be working.
Insight would be much appreciated - I'm really stumped.

I've also tried using the split() function with "\n" as the delimiter - this returned the same result.

Edit: Here is a sample of the output.

```
\nJean Valjean avait laissé, le plus d'argent possible aux pauvres. Après\ntout, de qui s'agissait-il? d'un forçat et d'une fille publique. C'est\npourquoi il simplifia l'enterrement de Fantine, et le réduisit à ce\nstrict nécessaire qu'on appelle la fosse commune.\n\nFantine fut donc enterrée dans ce coin gratis du cimetière qui est à\ntous et à personne, et où l'on perd les pauvres. Heureusement Dieu sait\noù retrouver l'âme. On coucha Fantine dans les ténèbres parmi les\npremiers os venus; elle subit la promiscuité des cendres. Elle fut jetée\nà la fosse publique. Sa tombe ressembla à son lit.\n\n\n\n\n","id":"17489"}]
```

Comment: Probably because you print them as one line. If you want to check wether there are different elements in the list you could e.g. add `\n' in the 'print'-statement.

Comment: Based on this example from W3Schools, among others, if the function had worked correctly, no newline characters should be visible.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_ref_string_splitlines
Printing lines as a whole has the same result.

Comment: I also printed the length of lines and got 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I go to that URL, I see that it's loading the content as plain text--even though it looks like a JSON object. Therefore in `get_les_mis()`, `text` is coming back as a string.

You may want to try loading it as JSON:

```py
import urllib.request
import json

def get_les_mis():
    url = "http://corpus-db.org/api/id/17489/fulltext"
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
            text = (f.read().decode('utf-8'))

            # load the text as a JSON object here
            text_json_obj = json.loads(text)
            
            # convert lines into a list of 14K elements (split on '\n')
            lines = text_json_obj[0]['text'].split('\n')
            for line in lines:
                print(line)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print(e.reason)
```

[image: See the lines variable debugged below]

Comment: Thank you so much! This made sense of it! I now understand the significance of the brackets at the beginning and end of the text.

Answer (score 0):

your data is a json object, read it as json first

```
  with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
        import json
        text = f.read().decode('utf-8')
        data = json.loads(text)
        lines = data[0]['text'].splitlines()
        for line in lines:
            print(line)
```